# Openconnect 7.08 update issues on linux mint 18.3

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, linux-mint

I am relatively new to the ubuntu linux world and am having trouble connecting to my school's VPN network. I cannot get the GUI based client Pulse Secure to install properly on my machine and my schools tech help is useless for anything linux. So, I have been trying to use openconnect to connect to said VPN in terminal. I have been unsuccessful so far because the VPN requires openconnect 7.08 and I currently am on 7.06. I have tried a simple sudo apt-get upgrade openconnect command to update and it says the version is current. I am new to this whole thing so I could be missing something very simple. No scripts to force install the version I have found have worked.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried a simple sudo apt-get upgrade openconnect command to update and it says the version is current.

What this means is that the latest version that is available to your distribution of Linux Mint (18.3) is openconnect version 7.06.

That being said, openconnect version 7.06 may be able to connect your your VPN. Try:

`sudo openconnect --juniper vpn.yourdomain.edu`

Also, try to install `network-manager-openconnect-gnome` (`apt-get install network-manager-openconnect-gnome`) if you have network manager installed. It has a GUI interface which allows you to create a new VPN connection, and you may choose 'Juniper' from a list.

See:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032792/openconnect-juniper-vpn-not-working-in-ubuntu-18-04
- https://serverfault.com/questions/363061/how-to-connect-to-a-juniper-vpn-from-linux